# android widget within a widget not working as intended

Tags: java, android, listview, button, android-framelayout

I use a FrameLayout as a custom list item. I have an onItemClickListener set up to the listView but my items each have a button within themselves, and while the button in them is clickable, the item itself is not and they're supposed to do different things. How do I make the item as well as the button within it both clickable?

Here's the code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProjectCreateScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondary_layout1);

    final TextView noProject = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NOPROJECT);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);

    final ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
    final ListAdapter addAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.list_item, R.id.listFrame, listItems);
    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    lv.setAdapter(addAdapter);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            noProject.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            listItems.add("New Project");
            ((ArrayAdapter) addAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent switchToEdit = new Intent(ProjectCreateScreen.this,
                    teamCreateScreen.class);
            startActivity(switchToEdit);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;

}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

The custom listView item xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listFrame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

    <Button android:id="@+id/frameBtn"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

The xml of the activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/rl">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="@string/AddProject"
    android:id="@+id/addBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/noProjectsNotice"
    android:id="@+id/NOPROJECT"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addBtn"
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:visibility="invisible">
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following two attributes for any view you want to be clickable inside the listview:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

That should solve most cases. If that is not enough, also add the following attribute to the root layout of your list view layout

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```